Clarification about user-provided explicitly-defaulted function being implicitly defined as deleted
As per the document, which says that (emphasis mine):

A function is user-provided if it is user-declared and not explicitly
defaulted or deleted on its first declaration. A user-provided
explicitly-defaulted function (i.e., explicitly defaulted after its
first declaration) is defined at the point where it is explicitly
defaulted; if such a function is implicitly defined as deleted, the
program is ill-formed. Declaring a function as defaulted after its
first declaration can provide efficient execution and concise
definition while enabling a stable binary interface to an evolving
code base.

How to understand the bolded text in the right way?
The aforementioned user-provided explicitly-defaulted function can be a default constructor, copy constructor or assignment operator which is marked as default, for example:
struct trivial
{
    trivial() = default;
    trivial(const trivial&) = default;
    trivial(trivial&&) = default;
    trivial& operator=(const trivial&) = default;
    trivial& operator=(trivial&&) = default;
    ~trivial() = default;
};

If my understanding above is correct, why does the document say that if such a function is implicitly defined as deleted, the program is ill-formed. I think the code works fine for the code below.
struct trivial
{
    trivial() = delete;
    trivial(int){};
    trivial(const trivial&) = delete;
    trivial(trivial&&) = delete;
    trivial& operator=(const trivial&) = delete;
    trivial& operator=(trivial&&) = delete;
    ~trivial() = delete;
};


The crucial points you're missing are "explicitly defaulted after its first declaration" (my emphasis) – i.e. the first declaration is not a definition – and that nothing is implicitly defined as deleted in any of your snippets.

This
struct foo {
    std::unique_ptr<int> x; 
    foo(const foo&);             // user provided
};

foo::foo(const foo&) = default;  // explicitly defaulted

is ill-formed. The copy constructor is user-provided, because its first declaration is neither defaulted nor deleted. The class has a non-copyable member, hence the copy constructor is implicitly-deleted. Later declaring the copy constructor as defaulted is ill-formed. The error is:
<source>:8:1: note: 'foo::foo(const foo&)' is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
    8 | foo::foo(const foo&) = default;
      | ^~~
<source>:8:1: error: use of deleted function 'std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>::unique_ptr(const std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>&) [with _Tp = int; _Dp = std::default_delete<int>]'
In file included from /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-14.1.0/include/c++/14.1.0/memory:78,
                 from <source>:1:
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-14.1.0/include/c++/14.1.0/bits/unique_ptr.h:516:7: note: declared here
  516 |       unique_ptr(const unique_ptr&) = delete;
      |       ^~~~~~~~~~
<source>:8:1: note: use '-fdiagnostics-all-candidates' to display considered candidates
    8 | foo::foo(const foo&) = default;
      | ^~~

In your examples nothing is implicitly deleted nor user-provided because you declare all of them explicitly as either defaulted or deleted on their first declaration.

Note that this is fine
struct foo {
    std::unique_ptr<int> x;
    foo(const foo&) = default;
    foo() = default;
};

Here default means "use the default" and because std::unique_ptr cannot be copied, foo has no copy constructor. It's not an error. And that's why the section you quote makes the distinction between user-provided and not user-provided.
